Unable to set custom colors for LSP errors
I have a custom color scheme and I've provided colors for LSPDiagnostics and Errors, but none of them are working. 
As seen, errors should be red, but the errors I see are yellowish in color

Tried a bunch of other highlight groups, but nothing seems to work.
I'm using neovim version 0.10 (which is the version that broke the LSP colors).

I believe the highlighting group to use is: DiagnosticVirtualTextError.
Since like:

DiagnosticFloatingError
DiagnosticSignError
DiagnosticVirtualTextError
NvimTreeDiagnosticErrorIcon
it is, by default, linked to DiagnosticError.

It is probably wise to modify DiagnosticError instead.
You have the same kind of highlighting groups for the other families:

Error
Warn
Info
Hint
Ok

Remark: I have used :hi command to find the potential culprits based on the color of the actual message.

This was it. Thanks

Thanks for the feedback :-)
